# Привязка к родительскому элементу Xamarin

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, binding

У меня есть юзер контрол:

```
<ContentView.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Frame x:Name="PasswordFrame" Padding="0">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Entry Grid.Row="0"
                           x:Name="Password"
                           Text="Password"
                           IsPassword="True"
                           Placeholder="Password"/>
                    <Label Grid.Row="1"
                           x:Name="PasswordErrorLabel"
                           TextColor="{DynamicResource ErrorColor}"
                           Padding="2" />
                </Grid>
            </Frame>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentView.Content>
```

Так же есть свойство в самом контроле:

```
public string PasswordText {
            get => (string) GetValue(PasswordTextProperty);
            set => SetValue(PasswordTextProperty, value);
        }
```

Как я могу привязать свойство 'Text' в Entry:

`Text="Password"` к свойству самого контрола? Как-то так:

```
Text = "{Binding PasswordText}"
```

Comment: Понимаю, что надо двигаться в сторону RelativeSource, но не понимаю как это реализовать

Answer (score 1):

Проблему решил!

```
  Text="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type controls:PasswordEntry},
                                AncestorLevel=1}, Path=PasswordText}"
```

Comment: `Text="{Binding PasswordText, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type controls:PasswordEntry}}}"`